# Keep separated values in stacked bar charts in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, duplicates, stacked-chart

I have this data in a file:

```
 protein,0,1,2,3,4
*Q76BS1_N_294,15,5,3,8,12
*N1NEW2_N_516,20,3,20
*B4DUL1_N_41,20,3,20
*F6R1P3_T_24,20,1,20
P80051_N_57,20,3,20
*F6QLE9_N_101,20,3,20
*A0A0M4QAG2_N_564,20,3,20
*G3RZA4_T_653,20,1,20
```

in another file I have the corresponding names to assign to each value contain in the column 0,1,2,3,4:

```
Kringle2_D,Cupin_1_D,PMP22_Claudin_O,nodomain4_N,Hormone_6_O,Interferon_O,Transferrin-like_D,nodomain633_N
nodomain289_N,glycosite_N_G,glycosite_N_G,glycosite_T_G,glycosite_N_G,glycosite_N_G,glycosite_N_G,glycosite_T_G
glycosite_N_G,Cupin_1_D,PMP22_Claudin_O,nodomain25_N,Hormone_6_O,Interferon_O,Transferrin-like_D,nodomain654_N
nodomain297_N,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
Kringle3_D,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
```

And I need to make stacked bar charts to represent the values in the columns 0,1,2,3,4 keeping the exact order in which they appeared.
I succeed in doing the graph bu ggplot2 unifies the bars having the same value (the same name reported in the second file) in a unique bar.

This is the graph I generated so far: [image]

As you can see, except for the first, the last and the fifth bars, the other ones are not keeping the variable "glycosite_N_G " in the middle, separating the other two variables because those are of the same type, for example Cupin_1_D or Transferrin-like_D..

I would like to have them separated even if they are identical because the order is important and it is specified in my data.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

da=read.csv('dataInterval.csv', h=T)

da2=read.csv('domainName.csv', h=F, stringsAsFactors=F)
avector <- c(t(da2))

da$protein <- factor(da$protein, da$protein)
data.lng <- melt(da, id=c("protein"))
data.lng["names"] <- factor(avector, levels=unique(avector))

le <- length(unique(data.lng$variable))
re <- replicate(le, "white")

ggplot(na.omit(data.lng), aes(x=protein, weight=value, fill=names),     size=0.5) +
geom_bar(width = 0.1) +
coord_flip() +
scale_x_discrete("Accession number",  expand=c(0.02, 0)) +
labs(x="X Label", y="amino acids position", title="Domains around   glycosites")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a few calculations, you can do this with `geom_segment` instead of `geom_bar`.  You need to calculate the start and end points of the segments within each protein based on your "value" variable.  The end points are the cumulative sum of value.  The start points are 0 for the first segment and lag cumulative sum for the other segments.

I do this work in dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
dat.seg = data.lng %>% 
    na.omit %>%
    group_by(protein) %>%
    arrange(protein) %>%
    mutate(end = cumsum(value), 
           start = c(0, na.omit(lag(end))))
```

Which looks like:

```
Source: local data frame [26 x 6]
Groups: protein [8]

             protein variable value              names   end start
              <fctr>   <fctr> <int>             <fctr> <int> <dbl>
1  *A0A0M4QAG2_N_564       X0    20 Transferrin-like_D    20     0
2  *A0A0M4QAG2_N_564       X1     3      glycosite_N_G    23    20
3  *A0A0M4QAG2_N_564       X2    20 Transferrin-like_D    43    23
4       *B4DUL1_N_41       X0    20    PMP22_Claudin_O    20     0
5       *B4DUL1_N_41       X1     3      glycosite_N_G    23    20
6       *B4DUL1_N_41       X2    20    PMP22_Claudin_O    43    23
...
```

Now plot with `geom_segment`.  With `geom_segment` you can build the plot horizontally rather than using `coord_flip`.

```
ggplot(dat.seg, aes(y = protein, color = names)) +
    geom_segment(aes(yend = protein, x = start, xend = end), size = 2) +
    scale_x_continuous("Accession number", expand=c(0.02, 0)) +
    labs(x="X Label", y="amino acids position", title="Domains around glycosites")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @aosmith! This is exactly what I needed! Do you know even how to make to start the x axis from 1 instead of zero? I know this seems a basic modification, but I am trying to do it since a week and I can't have the result I want....

Comment: @Alessandra You are welcome.  If this answers your question you can click the check mark next to the answer.  To start at 1 and keep everything else the same, use 1 in place of 0 when calculating the lag of the cumulative sum.  So in `start = c(0, na.omit...)`, replace the 0 with 1.

Comment: I up-voted your answer but since I have less than 15 of reputation is not showed... If I can do something else to accept your reply I would be very pleased to do it!

Comment: @Alessandra To accept an answer, click on the grey check mark next to it. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)